# Sending MMS via Twilio and Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

I've setup my google app script to be able to send an SMS via Twilio and that all works.  I'd like to be able to send an MMS by providing the mediaURL.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
function sendSms(to, body) {
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/sidxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzxxx/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "+12015551234",
    "mediaUrl" : "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("sidxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:keyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}
```

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: That's the thing.  I'm not getting any errors back.  I don't think that twilio is seeing it as an MMS message.  I've never tried MMS from google app script so I'm not sure what is missing.

Comment: Have you figured out a solution? I am running into the exact same thing.

Comment: Sorry.. I have not.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks to me as though your `mediaUrl` parameter is wrong. It's a small change that should fix it though.

The parameter should be capitalized. So [try it as `MediaUrl` instead](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#include-media-in-your-messages).

Let me know if that helps at all?